# Opening WebView links in default browser

Tags: android

I want to open my `WebWiew` links in default browser. I used this code but it did not work. Even the log did not show up.

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {

                Log.d("urlLoading",url);
                view.getContext().startActivity(
                        new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)));
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the source of WebView define http:// as link prefix.

example:

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.x/">..</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the in your onClickListner

`Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View v) { Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://google.com/"); Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri); startActivity(intent); } });`

Comment: I dont have any button. just I have a `WebView`

Comment: I Know that with this code I can open links with default browser. but problem is that this codes not run in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method

Comment: How do you intend to open the link in default browser if there is no button